# Raspberry Pi sometimes detects wrong keypad number

Tags: raspberry-pi, keypad

I am using a 3 x 4 Sparkfun keypad connected to a Raspberry Pi.

The issue I am facing is that 40% of the time wrong keypad numbers get detected after pressing the button.

For example, when I press "6", "3" is detected which is directly above "6." The same happens with "5" and "2" and likewise in the 2nd and 3rd row. No issue occurs in the first row as no buttons are above it.

I have used the below code by following a tutorial. I don't know if it's a software or a hardware issue.  I have two of these keypads and the same problem occurs in both.

```
def readLine(line, characters):
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.HIGH)
    if(GPIO.input(C1) == 1):
            print(characters[0])
    if(GPIO.input(C2) == 1):
                print(characters[1])
    if(GPIO.input(C3) == 1):
            print(characters[2])
    if(GPIO.input(C4) == 1):
            print(characters[3])
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.LOW)

try:
    while True:
            readLine(L1, ["1","2","3","A"])
            readLine(L2, ["4","5","6","B"])
            readLine(L3, ["7","8","9","C"])
            readLine(L4, ["*","0","#","D"])
            time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nApplication stopped!")
```

Comment: Do you have a question about electrical/electronic engineering that is compatible with this site's rules and guidelines?

Comment: I'd almost wonder about capacitance causing a holdover of the previous select but then would expect it to run in the opposite direction you report.  Try changing the order in which you do the readLine() calls and see if the problem changes.  You might also try adding a time delay, but that may be tricky.  In an MCU you'd definitely want a time delay for the row select outputs to change, here it's hard to know how fast this really runs.

Comment: Can you show the circuit diagram?

Comment: Are there pull-down resistors on inputs? Either physical or internal? Can you link to which specific keyboard is to understand better what you are working with? Also is there any init code for the GPIO pins?

Comment: These keypads usually don't have pull-up/down resistors, and leave input lines without a key press floating. How did you define the input pins on the Pi?

Comment: THis is probably a matrixed keypad, meaning each button doesn't go into a specific I/O, rather entire row/columns feed into a single I/O.   The software scans each row/column to see what's being pressed.  The symptom you're describing suggests to me an error in how the keypad is being scanned.    Go on a raspberry Pi or Sparkfun forum, you'll probably find somebody who knows more about this specific thing.    The keypad internally probably looks something like this:  https://www.embeddedrelated.com/blogimages/MichaelSilva/keypad_matrix_pu.png

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how quickly a Raspberry Pi will execute your code but I think the most likely explanation of your problem is that you are changing the output line and not giving it a chance to stabilise (and for the previous one to turn off).

```
GPIO.output(line, GPIO.HIGH)
if(GPIO.input(C1) == 1):
        print(characters[0])
```

Try introducing a delay in between the first and second line above. (If there isn't a handy delay function then give it a cubed root to solve!)

Comment: This is probably it.  The Python code sends a request to a service to switch the GPIO.  That's asynchronous to the read, and the read just returns the last known value rather than waiting for a poll of the port.

Comment: @JRE I highly doubt there is an asynchronicity here.  There are indeed several levels of things going on between python, the Linux kernel, and possibly the GPU (which IIRC may actually own the hardware), but a claim of asynchronicity and cached results is going to require some supporting documentary evidence.  What is more likely is simply slew rate or undriven input issues.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  The GPIO access is through the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) system.  The Python module sends requests to the pigpio daemon (service) that runs in a separate process.  You have no direct access to the hardware.  Writing to an output doesn't block until the hardware output is set.  You send the request, and your code continues execution while the pigpio daemon does its thing.  The hardware state changes whenever the daemon gets around to it.

Comment: @JRE do you have any *actual* documentation or evidence that pigpio operations from the same client are allowed to occur out of order or return cached results?  If that were the case, presumably people would be seeing failures left and right and there should seemingly be rather bold warnings in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain about the solution, but here are a couple of suggestions to help you:

1. in your code, you can try to use debounce to detect presses.
2. check with your wiring and schematics, in case there is the need for a pullup/pulldown resistor on the data line or a decoupling capacitor, to clear any noise.

Comment: The pulling resistor is the one possibly valid idea in this, the rest is mistaken.  Debouncing would only be relevant subsequent to a correct detection, and would only result in repeats, not mixed up keys.  Adding a capacitor will make things *worse*, not better, there's a fair chance that the current problem *is* stray capacitance.